# certain output of x numbers

Tags: python

i would like to make a program that takes an integer and gives a string of the amount of numbers of that integer.  For example, if the integer is 7, it gives 7777777, or if its 3, it give 333. Thank you

Comment: Well I tried to convert the integer into a string.  I am in a computer math class in high school and i need help for this certain question that requires a program like this.

Comment: So far i have def NamountofN(n): 
                   n=str'n'
and from there i don't know what to do

Comment: @Ronnie, then you should tag this question as homework, edit your question to show us the work you've done so far and explain exactly where your problem is.

Comment: @Carl: Homework is a meta tag and is discouraged. Stop telling people to edit their question to include the homework tag.

Comment: @Falmarri, is that new?  The homework has been used on this site for years.  There are 5000+ questions tagged with it right now - since when do we do people's homework?  In addition, the highest rated answer on the meta discussion is to keep the homework tag.

Comment: @Ronnie, your question update seems ... disjointed. Do you want a deterministic 333/55555 type program or one that generates random 1s and 0s? How did you get from the former to the latter?

Comment: @Carl: It's relatively new I guess. I can't find the link to post on meta right now.

Comment: @Ronnie, it's not a good idea to change the _entire basis_ of your question since it invalidates answers already given. If you want to ask a different question (and what you changed it to was _vastly_ different), please ask another question.

Comment: It was a blog entry: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ although there was some discussion as to whether homework tags should still be allowed. My POV is that they're not since they can't stand alone and, if questioners want help rather than answers, they should make that clear in the question. Others may disagree.

Comment: One of the nicest mess I've seen on SO :P Asking the right question the right way is an art that has to be learned. Please learn it ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
def mkstr(n):
    return n * str(n)

print mkstr(3)
print mkstr(7)
```

It outputs:

```
333
7777777
```

as expected. This is the simplest Pythonic way to do it but, if this *does* turn out to be a homework question, you'll probably be expected to do this as a loop, something like the pseudo-code:

```
define mkstr(num):
    set str to ""
    count = num
    while count is greater than zero:
        append string version of num to str
        subtract one from count
    return str
```

Comment: but can you somehow make the output into a random string of 0's and 1's? and the order changes every time you try the program?

Comment: And ofcourse, a take a beginner book and start reading Python so that you can do your further  homeworks on your own.

Comment: Thank you, I am currently taking computer math and am using Python but have difficulty using it

Comment: What does printing the number 'n', n times have to do with printing a random number of 0s and 1s

Comment: Hold on, it'll be better if i write the actual question

Comment: No it won't. We don't care about the question. We want to know what problems YOU'RE having in your understanding and/or code. Not the problem your teacher gives you.

Comment: Oh ok then. the only actual problem is applying the randint into the program

Comment: @Falmarri, the original question was nothing like the changed one. I've informed Ronnie that he should post _another_ question rather than making massive changes to already-asked-and-answered ones.